# Suppress computation in table

Tags: functions

I want to define a vector-function in the following (simplified) way

```
f[x_List]:=Table[x[[i]]+x[[i+1]],{i,1,Length[x]-1}]
```

BUT operations such as $f[x]+f[y]$ shouldn't be evaluated entry-wise, i.e. for $x \neq y$ the values $f[x]$ and $f[y]$ should be treated 'as if they have nothing to do with each other'.. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: For example `f[{x,y}]-f[{x,0}]-f[{y,0}]` gives `{0}`, but I want `{x+y}-{x}-{y}`.. so the list entries should rather be treated as abstract symbols than as integers

Comment: The problem is, if `f[x]` and `f[y]` output lists, and you add them, they will add entry-wise. What exactly do you mean by 'as if they had nothing to do with each other`? *Please give an example input with the desired output.* That will help us immensely.

Comment: `f` can be written as `f[x_List] := Most[x] + Rest[x]`

Comment: @march thx, I edited it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want something like this:

```
f[x_?VectorQ] := Most @ x + Rest @ x // Evaluate // Defer
```

then

```
f[{x,y}] + f[{x,0}] + f[{0,y}]
```

> {x} + {y} + {x + y}

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want, thx!

Comment: @gwr +1 for the approach. I also used `Defer` but in a different way  with `Hold`

Comment: You might also write: `f[x : {__}] := Defer @@ {Most@x + Rest@x}`.  This also does not attempt to evaluate in the case of `f[{}]` which otherwise fails with errors.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_List] := Table[Hold[{#}] &@(x[[i]] + x[[i + 1]]), {i, 1, Length[x] - 1}]
Defer@@(f[{x, y}] + f[{x, 0}] + f[{y, 0}]) /. Hold[arg_] :> arg

(* {x} + {y} + {x + y} *)
```